# Reduced resolution when exporing raster with layout view using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, export, layouts

I have an ArcGIS project with raster and vector layers. I use the function `Export map ...` to export `layout view` to a tiff file with different DPI values (150 and 300). The resulting image is very different from what is displayed in the ArcGIS. The resolution of the raster layer is highly distorted regardless of the DPI option.

**How to fix this issue?**

[image]
**Pic 1.** ArcGIS layout view (natural raster layer resolution).
[image]
**Pic 2.** Export result - DPI 150 (raster layer resolution reduced).
[image]
**Pic 3.** Export result - DPI 300 (raster layer resolution reduced same way as with DPI 150).

Comment: Under the Format tab when you export, do you have any compression on your Tiff export?

Comment: @Rex Yes, LZW. But it is lossless compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the custom projection of the raster layer. Reprojecting raster data into a data frame projection solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest bumping the DPI to 600, changing the file type to PNG format and changing the resample during display using to Bilinear Interpolation (for continuous data)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem.